# How could such an automorphisms in $Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2$ be achieved?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, automorphism-group

I came across this problem on brilliant. and to my understanding, the definition of automorphisms is to map a group to itself with bijective mapping which means the origin group and the mapped group must have elementwise pairings.

and according to brilliant answer:

> An automorphism is determined uniquely by what elements the three
> generators $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ turn into under the map.
> The first one can turn into any of seven nontrivial elements. The
> second one can turn into any of six elements (not the identity and not
> what $(1,0,0)$ turned into). The third one can turn into any of four
> elements (it can't turn into any of the four elements generated by the
> images of the first two generators). So, the answer is $7 \cdot 6 \cdot 4 = 168$.
>
> In fact, the automorphism group is $GL_3({\mathbb F}_2)$, the group of
> with coefficients in $\{0, 1\}$ modulo $2$.

I wonder how could it be possible to let's say map
`(1, 0, 0)` to `(0, 0, 1)`,
`(0, 1, 0)` to `(0, 1, 0)` and
`(0, 0, 1)` to `(0, 1, 1)` and still have `(1, x, x)` mapped back to origin group? the first `1` seems not to be able to be generated through any combinations of mapped generators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your counterexample does not satisfy the conditions required by the construction.

Starting with
$$
(1,0,0) \mapsto (0,0,1)
$$
is fine, as is extending the construction by
$$
(0,1,0) \mapsto (0,1,0)
$$
But the construction then requires that $(0,0,1)$ is not sent to any element that can be generated by the images of the generators considered so far.

However, $(0,0,1)+(0,1,0) = (0,1,1)$, so the conditions prohibit sending $(0,0,1)$ to $(0,1,1)$.

Comment: thanks, that makes perfectly sense. that's the reason the answer is 7*6*4 instead of 7*6*5: the 4 exclude both previous selections and the combination of previous selections.